Do access points overwhelm the main router?
Let's say a router has the capacity for 100 users, but I have 3 different access points with 100 users each. For the main router, would that count as 300 users or just 3?

to piggyback on @John's comment, OpenWrt's Wireless Access Point (aka "Dumb" Access Point) wiki explains why that is

What other approach then should I use for a large number of users? Just getting a coorporate-tier router?

Depends on whether the users on those APs are using the Internet or LAN resources. after all traffic destined for the LAN won't be processed by the router at all. if they are going to use the Internet primarily however, you have overbooked it by 200%. to more directly respond to your question, no APs don't overwhelm routers, users and devices on those APs overwhelm routers.

It depends on what exactly is being measured.
Wi-Fi clients connected to access points don't count when it comes to measuring radio capacity (assuming they're all on different channels or sufficiently far apart) – after all, they're talking to the AP's radio, not the router's.
But they do count when it comes to other things such as total throughput, or the number of IP addresses (DHCP leases), or the number of NAT tracked connections. For example, with 300 devices, you do need an IP subnet and DHCP pool configured large enough to fit those 300 addresses, and the router needs enough RAM to be able to NAT all the concurrent connections that they make.
(The latter is easy to solve once you have access points, though – it means you can get a dedicated router for them without having to compromise on WiFi capabilities.)
